# Variables keep resetting to null in C# application, why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am building a desktop app. In `Program.cs` I have this:

```
public struct Settings
{
     public string SiteName;
     public string IP3Oktets;
     public string Data_Source;
     public string Initial_Catalog;
     public string officialCardNumber;
     public bool KarticaUcitacu;
     public Dictionary<string, object> KarticuUbacio;
     public Dictionary<string, object> Korisnik;
     public Dictionary<string, object> PoslednjiUgovor;
     public Version Version;
     public string userName;
}

public static Settings mySettings = new Settings();
```

So only one object to hold app-wide properties.

Then during the logon process I set them up - a procedure that gets data from the database looks like this:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> IzŠifreKartice(string pKartica)
{
     SqlParameter[] @params =
     {
         new SqlParameter("@KARTICA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15) { Value = pKartica },
     };

     DataTable dt = DB.GetData("SELECT * FROM ZAPOSLENI WHERE KARTICA = @KARTICA", @params);

     if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
     {
          return dt.Rows[0].Table.Columns
                   .Cast<DataColumn>()
                   .ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => dt.Rows[0][c]);  ;
     } 
     else
     {
          return null;
     }
}
```

Now, based on some condition I have to open another login prompt and I do it like this (I also show here the main form):

```
    this.Hide();
    var form2 = new frm_glavna(); //main form
    form2.Closed += (ss, args) => this.Close();
    form2.Show();
    var form3 = new frm_RazduživanjeLogin(); //another login 
    form3.ActiveControl = form3.txt_Lozinka;

    form3.ShowDialog(this);
```

And after that, when the main form opens, I lose all `Dictionary<string, object>` values (they become null).

What I am doing wrong here? Is it possible that the program is keeping their references instead of values?

Thanks,
Dejan

update:

- after the first login

[image]

- on second login, but before changing any properties of mySettings global variable.

[image]

**FIXED!**

I have found that this was causing problem:

```
Program.Settings s = Program.mySettings;
```

it seems that this actually copy object somehow instead just keeping a reference on mySettings variable, so I remove it. I will use Program.mySettings even if that is much more to write.

Thanks

Comment: I never saw you assign a value to your dictionary in your struct but to be honest I'd recommend you use the built in settings system rather than rolling your own

Comment: It's unclear how your are assigning the values or where the struct instance is being stored. Both of those would be important pieces of information. But I'd suspect maybe if you're closing a form where that setting variable was declared, and then re-creating it later, that could be the cause of the issue. Try just hiding the form instead

Comment: Ive added some photos to show you what I am talking about, note that frm_login is only hidden not destroyed, you will see that only some variables are lost, that ones that are set in frm_login

Comment: let us assume that after hiding frm_login all variables set there are lost, how I can make a copy and preserver them. Note that in Delphi I didn't have such problems.

Comment: We don't need photos, we believe you. We just need enough code to understand how it works and be able to suggest a fix

Comment: @ADyson, thanks but do you know why using Program.Settings s = Program.mySettings on every form actually caused the issue?

Comment: struct is value type if you changed that to a class if would copy by reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `Settings` type from a `struct` to a `class`, and C# won't copy it on assignment anymore.